# how to send alert message from HttpResponseRedirect django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in bootstrap modal.
When user submit this form it send a post request to a url(/submitform),
view of /submitform does something with the data (rearrange it) 
and do a "requests.post" to another url.
Now depending on the second post request success or failure. I want to display an alert on HttpResponseRedirect url.

here's the code:

```
payload= {"createRequest":
                  { "users": request.POST["newuser"],
                    "email": request.POST["newemail"]
                    }
                  }
headers =  {'content-type' : 'application/json'}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1.0/newuser',
                          data=json.dumps(payload),
                          headers=headers, verify=False)

return HttpResponseRedirect("/dashboard/all_users", {"alert":r.content})
```

and in views of all_users it checks if alert exist (because all_users has been called from several other places where alert is not part of it), if alert exist it send it to html from its render_to_respons.

I cant change all_users url format, its been used at a lot of places. 
Let me know if more clarifications needed.

Things I have tried:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("/dashboard/all_users"), kwargs={"alert":r.content})
```

error:

> Reverse for '/dashboard/all_users' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found.

Answer (score 3):

In your template, you can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
   {% if alert %}
      //whatever conditions and js code
      alert('{{alert}}');
   {% endif %}
 });
</script>
```

and in views, use [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) instead of `HttpResponseRedirect`

```
return redirect(reverse("/dashboard/all_users"), {"alert":r.content})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I already have a similar condition to check if alert exist or not, in the template. Problem here is its not passing args (alert) with HttpResponseRedirect.

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/all_users/newuserform
Reverse for '/dashboard/all_users' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: Looks like the URL is not resolving correctly. Check the url patterns. Is it a valid URL ?

Comment: url(r'^/dashboard/all_users$', DashboardUserListView.as_view(), name="DashboardUser"),

Comment: If it is an extension of a url, my guess is, the leading `/` needs to be removed. Can you access this URL directly in a browser?